# Survival analysis with different follow-up times in exposure groups

Tags: survival, cox-model

I have been asked to help analyse some recurrent-events survival data (using an Anderson-Gill model) looking at risk of disease relapse among two different subtypes of the disease (primary covariate) adjusting for other covariates. That's all fine.

I was then advised that the subtype groups were systematically different in the period of time they had been observed - one group had a shorter period of follow-up then the other. The question was then, how does the survival model account for the longer observed group having greater opportunity to have more events?

I have been trying to think about whether this violates any censoring assumptions (independent, non-informative) and I don't think it does? But I also can't articulate an answer to their question? Can anyone help?

(This question is related: [Cox model with different follow-up times in groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141207/cox-model-with-different-follow-up-times-in-groups))

Answer (score 0):

Your first guess was correct, this is a clear example of covariate dependent censoring. The time of (right-)censoring is clearly dependent on the which value the "subtype" variable takes. You can see this directly if you invert the status variable (from 0=censored, 1=event to 0=event, 1=censored) and fit a Cox-model to the data. You should then see a clear effect of the subtype variable on the censoring.

I am no expert on analysing survival data with dependent censoring, but these articles may help you with your problem: https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/66/1/239/7098980 and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3818252/

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not convinced the censoring is dependent, but maybe I'm not understanding. From: Survival Analysis A Self-Learning Text (Kleinbaum) - "Independent censoring essentially means that within any subgroup of interest, the subjects who are censored at time t should be representative of all the subjects in that subgroup who remained at risk at time t with respect to their survival experience. In other words, censoring is independent provided that it is random within any subgroup of interest."